# How do I use log in a function?

Tags: calculus

I have $$f(x) = e^x + 2e^{2x} ,x\in \mathbb{R}$$

The question says find all solutions $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ of the equation $f(\ln \theta) = 1$.

How to I graph this?

Comment: Note, if you mean to say $2e^{2x}$, you need to put curly braces around everything that gets lifted into the superscript.

Comment: @Tac-Tics thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you meant $\;f(x)=e^x+2e^{2x}\;$ then

$$1=f(\log\theta)=e^{\log\theta}+2e^{2\log\theta}=\theta+2\theta^2$$

Now just solve the easy quadratic

$$2\theta^2+\theta-1=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Plug and chug:

$f(x) = e^x + 2e^{2x}$, so $f(\ln \theta) = e^{\ln(\theta)} + 2e^{2 \ln \theta} = 1$.

From here, you can use the laws of logarithms to simplify this expression. You'll end up with a familiar polynomial equation to solve.